# EF Fluent Mapping not loading all children with eager loading using Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I've created two entities which are related to each other by joining using three columns, both are views on the database. For the `Travel` I have the `Id`, `FromCityId` and `ToCityId`, for `TravelCost` I have the `TravelId`, `FromCityId` and `ToCityId`. The fluent mapping is as below

`TravelEntityConfiguration` class:

```
HasMany(x => x.Amounts)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(x => new
    {
        x.TravelId,
        x.FromCityId,
        x.ToCityId
    });
```

and for the travel cost its

```
TravelCostEntityConfiguration

HasRequired(x => x.Travel)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => new
    {
        x.TravelId,
        x.FromCityId,
        x.ToCityId
    });
```

When i query these entities and include the navigation property

```
context.Set<Table>().Include(x => x.TravelCost)....
```

For each result only the first of the child collection is loaded. I checked the query generated, even the query is correct it returns the full set with all the children and the join is correctly. What am i missing here. Need some help no clue for the moment. basically i suspect the mapping is not correct but didn't found out the problem yet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You will get everything as you access it.

Comment: I know but i assure you it's not the case if you need more information just ask me

Comment: As strange it seams you can have a look on the records and entities

Comment: There's something weird going on in your screenshot. Why do all three records have the same ID?

Comment: I did not include all the columns, basically it's the id of the travel record and at the end are the ids of the child records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Asad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726343/asad-saeeduddin), you lighted up my problem. The problem was with the Id of the TravelCost view which were generated on the fly and ended up to be the same so EF thinks it is the same record, the mapping was totally correct.